# MSBuild Script gets "Win32Exception: The system cannot find the File Specified"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild

I have built an MSBuild script that automates a daily deployment of the most recent code checked in for our programming team to one of 2 or 3 servers (depending on paramaters) for testing.  I also wrote a quick BAT file to start it that just calls "MSBuild.exe" with the given parameters.  Within the MSBuild script, the first thing it does is a "Get Latest" from TFS.  Here is a code snippet...

```
<Project DefaultTargets="BuildLatest" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll" TaskName="TFSSource"/>
```

...

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TFSourceLoc>$/SourceCode</TFSourceLoc>
</PropertyGroup>
```

...

```
<Target Name="BuildLatest" >
   <TFSSource TaskAction="Get" ItemCol="$(TFSourceLoc)" />
</Target>
```

The error comes back...
ERROR ...\AutoDeploy.xml(163,5): Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

... and the BAT file ends.

The really weird thing is that I can minimize VS 2010 and run this exact same BAT file from Explorer with no issues.

So what am I not seeing? Why won't this run from within VS 2010?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot more research, which should have happened before I asked the question, but anyways...

Instead of calling a batch file, I decided to try the suggestion of calling MSBuild.exe directly and putting my parms (which will change every couple weeks with a new Sprint) in generic Response files.

I believe it was an issue with the Start/Initial Directory that was resolved by specifying the right directories on the "External Tools" dialog box.